# Why the register $v0 is caller saved?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers, mips32

I am studying MIPS architecture and I can't figure why the register `$v0` is caller saved.

This register is where the function stores the return value. When and why the caller must save it? May someone make a good example?

Comment: If this register stores the return value then it surely cannot be saved/restored by the callee, thus if you want to preserve it then the caller must be the one which saves it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is the register that will hold the return value, it cannot be callee-save. That would have created a situation where the callee both

- must change the register, in order to return a value in it, and
- is not allowed to change it (except temporarily), because it's callee-save.

So it's caller-save. This does not mean that the caller must save it, it just means that *if* the caller needs the value to persist across a call, *then* it must save it somewhere else.

Comment: "_if the caller needs the value to persist across a call_", this is exactly the point I don't understand. May you be more clear about this case?

Comment: @G.Guidi it is no different from the other caller-save registers: the caller has some value that it needs to keep, but it has to call a function that may overwrite the register in which that value is stored, so it has to be moved somewhere else (like on the stack or a callee-save register).

Comment: Oh, I figured it now. Thanks for the answer and the extra explanation.

Comment: @G.Guidi: I prefer the terminology "call clobbered" vs. "call preserved", because that avoids implying that anyone *has* to save it.  Good code will use call-clobbered registers for things that don't need to survive a call (because it's done with them).  Also, the terms differ by more than one letter.